# Android: JNI crash

Tags: java, crash, java-native-interface, clang

i'm developing android app that uses `Clang` via C API (libclang) for ARM.
I've wrote wrapper to `invoke clang_..()` functions and  map data between Java<->native code. So the app is working for few times and then crashing. It's interacting with native code from java background thread (if that helps).

My idea about what's wrong is:

1. i'm trying to delete already deleted pointer
2. there is a memory leak in my code/clang and heap is fully allocated
3. concurrency issue

Any thoughts are highly appreciated:

```
12-10 23:03:55.382: ASSERT/libc(2763): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000acb (code=0), thread 3690 (Thread-545)

// ...

12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): backtrace:
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #00  pc 0017b198  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::cxdiag::lazyCreateDiags(CXTranslationUnitImpl*, bool)+200)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #01  pc 00009028  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang_wrapper.so (Java_name_antonsmirnov_clang_clang_1wrapper_getDiagnostics+72)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #02  pc 0001fb70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #03  pc 0004e8b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+360)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #04  pc 00029020  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #05  pc 0002d7e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #06  pc 0005fed5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #07  pc 0005feff  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #08  pc 00055327  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #09  pc 00012e70  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #10  pc 000125c8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): stack:
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475be0  00000004
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475be4  1d300005
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475be8  76475c04  [stack:3690]
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475bec  735086e0
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475bf0  731a51c8
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475bf4  00000000
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475bf8  731a3f48
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475bfc  76475c80  [stack:3690]
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c00  7373df30
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c04  7160ca88
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c08  76475c7c  [stack:3690]
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c0c  40137ff1  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c10  75fcda38  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c14  402028ff  /system/lib/libstdc++.so (operator new[](unsigned int)+6)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c18  df0027ad
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c1c  00000000
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #00  76475c20  1d300005
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c24  7308de78
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c28  76475c54  [stack:3690]
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c2c  715ebdb0  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang_wrapper.so (unmapTranslationUnit+56)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c30  7308de78
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c34  715f1620  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang_wrapper.so
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c38  1d200005
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c3c  0008de78
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c40  1d300005
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c44  6da271c0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c48  7160ca78
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c4c  00000004
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c50  7373df38
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c54  715ef02c  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang_wrapper.so (Java_name_antonsmirnov_clang_clang_1wrapper_getDiagnostics+76)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #01  76475c58  6d707560  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c5c  1d300005
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c60  1d300001
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c64  7308de78
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c68  42802618  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c6c  731a51c8
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c70  7160ca78
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c74  7160cb20
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c78  76475c94  [stack:3690]
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c7c  41463b74  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): #02  76475c80  7373df2c
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c84  00000001
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c88  427fe0c8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c8c  741b6c52  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid-1.apk@classes.dex
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c90  00000000
12-10 23:03:55.883: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c94  414928bd  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+364)
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near r0:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c00 7373df30 7160ca88 76475c7c 40137ff1  0.ss..`q|\Gv...@
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c10 75fcda38 402028ff df0027ad 00000000  8..u.( @.'......
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c20 1d300005 7308de78 76475c54 715ebdb0  ..0.x..sT\Gv..^q
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c30 7308de78 715f1620 1d200005 0008de78  x..s ._q.. .x...
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c40 1d300005 6da271c0 7160ca78 00000004  ..0..q.mx.`q....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near r2:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265708 00000002 7326f158 72d26e70 7324d350  ....X.&spn.rP.$s
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265718 0000006a 00000000 00000050 00000043  j.......P...C...
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265728 00000001 401000f0 00000000 00000006  .......@........
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265738 0000000a 0000000a 00000008 00000000  ................
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265748 00000e60 749a3930 749a3930 00000000  `...09.t09.t....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near r4:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 735086c0 00790063 00750066 00760079 00000076  c.y.f.u.y.v.v...
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 735086d0 006a0020 00670062 00000068 0000001b   .j.b.g.h.......
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 735086e0 75fcda38 00000000 00000000 00000000  8..u............
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 735086f0 00000000 0000001b 00000001 00000001  ................
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73508700 72cfb378 00000000 00000018 000000bb  x..r............
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near r5:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a51a8 749a3930 749a3930 749a3930 00000000  09.t09.t09.t....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a51b8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000023  ............#...
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a51c8 715a1dc0 731a3f48 72dbafc0 735086e0  ..ZqH?.s...r..Ps
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a51d8 73121220 00000000 00000000 0000001b   ..s............
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a51e8 00000005 00000005 00000000 6e616c63  ............clan
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near r6:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265708 00000002 7326f158 72d26e70 7324d350  ....X.&spn.rP.$s
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265718 0000006a 00000000 00000050 00000043  j.......P...C...
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265728 00000001 401000f0 00000000 00000006  .......@........
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265738 0000000a 0000000a 00000008 00000000  ................
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 73265748 00000e60 749a3930 749a3930 00000000  `...09.t09.t....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near r7:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a3f28 00000001 00000001 70a57cd8 00000000  .........|.p....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a3f38 732657a8 70a32c28 00000020 000003b3  .W&s(,.p .......
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a3f48 75fcdfc8 731225f0 72d8ddd8 733af500  ...u.%.s...r..:s
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a3f58 715b2ac8 00000000 73043e00 73690600  .*[q.....>.s..is
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 731a3f68 734d9f88 00000000 00000000 00000000  ..Ms............
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near r8:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c60 1d300001 7308de78 42802618 731a51c8  ..0.x..s.&.B.Q.s
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c70 7160ca78 7160cb20 76475c94 41463b74  x.`q .`q.\Gvt;FA
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c80 7373df2c 00000001 427fe0c8 741b6c52  ,.ss.......BRl.t
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c90 00000000 414928bd 7373df2c 741b6c50  .....(IA,.ssPl.t
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475ca0 715eefe0 7160ca88 00000000 00000000  ..^q..`q........
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near r9:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7373df10 00000000 00000000 7373df48 7417562c  ........H.ss,V.t
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7373df20 6da271c0 00000000 00000000 1d300001  .q.m..........0.
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7373df30 1d300005 7373df84 741750a8 6da26b58  ..0...ss.P.tXk.m
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7373df40 7417562c 00000000 6d707560 00000000  ,V.t....`upm....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7373df50 00000000 00000000 00000006 1d200005  .............. .
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near sl:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7160ca68 00000002 00000000 00000010 00000453  ............S...
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7160ca78 74175628 7373df2c 6da26b58 70991000  (V.t,.ssXk.m...p
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7160ca88 427fded8 00000007 76475da8 00000000  ...B.....]Gv....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7160ca98 76475ddc 00000010 00000000 41463d00  .]Gv.........=FA
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7160caa8 00000000 00000000 6ca88670 7373a300  ........p..l..ss
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near fp:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c5c 1d300005 1d300001 7308de78 42802618  ..0...0.x..s.&.B
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c6c 731a51c8 7160ca78 7160cb20 76475c94  .Q.sx.`q .`q.\Gv
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c7c 41463b74 7373df2c 00000001 427fe0c8  t;FA,.ss.......B
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c8c 741b6c52 00000000 414928bd 7373df2c  Rl.t.....(IA,.ss
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c9c 741b6c50 715eefe0 7160ca88 00000000  Pl.t..^q..`q....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): memory near sp:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c00 7373df30 7160ca88 76475c7c 40137ff1  0.ss..`q|\Gv...@
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c10 75fcda38 402028ff df0027ad 00000000  8..u.( @.'......
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c20 1d300005 7308de78 76475c54 715ebdb0  ..0.x..sT\Gv..^q
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c30 7308de78 715f1620 1d200005 0008de78  x..s ._q.. .x...
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 76475c40 1d300005 6da271c0 7160ca78 00000004  ..0..q.mx.`q....
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): code around pc:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b178 ebff8235 e3560000 15963000 e1a0000d  5.....V..0......
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b188 e1a02006 12833001 15863000 e5973020  . ...0...0.. 0..
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b198 e5931408 eb0152d7 e59f305c e58d4018  .....R..\0...@..
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b1a8 e58d401c e08f3003 e2833008 e597412c  .@...0...0..,A..
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b1b8 e58d3000 e5977130 ea000002 e1a01004  .0..0q..........
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): code around lr:
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b15c e8800048 e580600c e5c06010 e585000c  H....`...`......
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b16c e3a00038 ebff779f e1a06000 ebff8235  8....w...`..5...
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b17c e3560000 15963000 e1a0000d e1a02006  ..V..0....... ..
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b18c 12833001 15863000 e5973020 e5931408  .0...0.. 0......
12-10 23:03:55.893: INFO/DEBUG(167): 7537b19c eb0152d7 e59f305c e58d4018 e58d401c  .R..\0...@...@..
12-10 23:03:55.923: DEBUG/WifiStateMachine(539): ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-4ms arg1=1 }
12-10 23:03:55.933: DEBUG/WifiStateMachine(539): L2ConnectedState{ what=131155 when=-4ms arg1=1 }
```

Another crash (probably another reason):

```
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): r0 00000027  r1 deadbaad  r2 4024cb0c  r3 00000000
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): r4 00000000  r5 7e7a82bc  r6 00000002  r7 00000002
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): r8 00000030  r9 7d3c0590  sl 7d3aae24  fp 40253a6c
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): ip 00004000  sp 7e7a82b8  lr 4021ec89  pc 4021b32a  cpsr 60000030
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d0  20656c6966206e69  d1  646564756c636e69
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d2  6f63206d6f726620  d3  645f6574656c706d
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d4  000002db000002c9  d5  000002ed000002ec
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d6  000003ae0000039c  d7  000003d4000003c1
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d8  4418800000000262  d9  4434000043898000
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d10 0000000042c00000  d11 0000000000000000
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d16 6769736e75202c2a  d17 29746e692064656e
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d18 6c63206e6f697461  d19 78654c3a3a676e61
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d20 537465673a3a7265  d21 636f4c656372756f
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d22 6863286e6f697461  d23 74736e6f63207261
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d28 0048004700460044  d29 004a0048004a0049
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
12-11 00:10:38.106: INFO/DEBUG(166): scr 28000013
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): backtrace:
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #00  pc 0001832a  /system/lib/libc.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #01  pc 0000dc04  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #02  pc 0001f0df  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+30)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #03  pc 0077c954  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::getSourceLocation(char const*, unsigned int) const+76)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #04  pc 0077ca4c  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::FormTokenWithChars(clang::Token&, char const*, clang::tok::TokenKind)+100)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #05  pc 00781098  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::LexTokenInternal(clang::Token&)+5616)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #06  pc 0015de68  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::LexFromRawLexer(clang::Token&)+116)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #07  pc 00781d3c  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::getRawToken(clang::SourceLocation, clang::Token&, clang::SourceManager const&, clang::LangOptions const&)+220)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #08  pc 00781d9c  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::MeasureTokenLength(clang::SourceLocation, clang::SourceManager const&, clang::LangOptions const&)+36)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #09  pc 001d1824  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::DiagnosticRenderer::emitMacroExpansions(clang::SourceLocation, clang::DiagnosticsEngine::Level, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::CharSourceRange>, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::FixItHint>, clang::SourceManager const&, unsigned int&, unsigned int)+840)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #10  pc 001d13ec  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::DiagnosticRenderer::emitDiagnostic(clang::SourceLocation, clang::DiagnosticsEngine::Level, llvm::StringRef, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::CharSourceRange>, llvm::ArrayRef<clang::FixItHint>, clang::SourceManager const*, llvm::PointerUnion<clang::Diagnostic const*, clang::StoredDiagnostic const*>)+1224)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #11  pc 001d1b20  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::DiagnosticRenderer::emitStoredDiagnostic(clang::StoredDiagnostic&)+304)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #12  pc 0017b1c8  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::cxdiag::lazyCreateDiags(CXTranslationUnitImpl*, bool)+248)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #13  pc 00009028  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang_wrapper.so (Java_name_antonsmirnov_clang_clang_1wrapper_getDiagnostics+72)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #14  pc 0001fb70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #15  pc 0004e8b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+360)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #16  pc 00029020  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #17  pc 0002d7e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #18  pc 0005fed5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #19  pc 0005feff  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #20  pc 00055327  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #21  pc 00012e70  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #22  pc 000125c8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): stack:
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a8278  00000000
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a827c  c6c488f5
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a8280  00001000
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a8284  00000262
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a8288  44188000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a828c  43898000  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a8290  40247774  /system/lib/libc.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a8294  4024cd10
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a8298  00000000
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a829c  4021ec89  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+32)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82a0  00000001
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82a4  7e7a82bc  [stack:5011]
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82a8  00000002
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82ac  00000002
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82b0  df0027ad
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82b4  00000000
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #00  7e7a82b8  75ff7ec2  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82bc  fffffbdf
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82c0  4023dbfc  /system/lib/libc.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82c4  00000002
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82c8  00000002
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82cc  4021e1f5  /system/lib/libc.so (fprintf+16)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82d0  40247718  /system/lib/libc.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82d4  75ff7ec2  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82d8  4023dbfc  /system/lib/libc.so
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82dc  40210c08  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_clone)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #01  7e7a82e0  7e7a82e0  [stack:5011]
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82e4  402220e3  /system/lib/libc.so (__assert2+34)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): #02  7e7a82e8  0000042d
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82ec  75feace7  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::getSourceLocation(char const*, unsigned int) const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82f0  75feace7  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::getSourceLocation(char const*, unsigned int) const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
12-11 00:10:38.126: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82f4  75a7c958  /data/data/name.antonsmirnov.android.arduinodroid/lib/libclang.so (clang::Lexer::getSourceLocation(char const*, unsigned int) const+80)
12-11 00:10:38.136: INFO/DEBUG(166): memory near r2:
12-11 00:10:38.136: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4024caec 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.136: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4024cafc 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.136: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4024cb0c 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.136: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4024cb1c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.136: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4024cb2c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.136: INFO/DEBUG(166): memory near r5:
12-11 00:10:38.136: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a829c 4021ec89 00000001 7e7a82bc 00000002  ..!@......z~....
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82ac 00000002 df0027ad 00000000 75ff7ec2  .....'.......~.u
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82bc fffffbdf 4023dbfc 00000002 00000002  ......#@........
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82cc 4021e1f5 40247718 75ff7ec2 4023dbfc  ..!@.w$@.~.u..#@
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82dc 40210c08 7e7a82e0 402220e3 0000042d  ..!@..z~. "@-...
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): memory near r9:
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3c0570 7d39c9fc 7e020006 0003be14 00000001  ..9}...~........
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3c0580 00000000 7e020015 0003be15 00000004  .......~........
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3c0590 7e313d3c 7e000069 0003be19 00000001  <=1~i..~........
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3c05a0 00000000 7e000016 0003be1e 0000000d  .......~........
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3c05b0 7e1cbd10 7e0200a6 00000000 00000002  ...~...~........
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): memory near sl:
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3aae04 7d3aae24 7d3aaf15 706d6f63 6574656c  $.:}..:}complete
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3aae14 6d65645f 6e692e6f 70632e6f 67670070  _demo.ino.cpp.gg
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3aae24 636e6923 6564756c 72413c20 6e697564  #include <Arduin
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3aae34 3e682e6f 7274730a 20746375 0a7b2073  o.h>.struct s {.
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7d3aae44 6e692020 3b692074 746e690a 203b6620    int i;.int f;
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): memory near fp:
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 40253a4c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 40253a5c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 40253a6c c6c488f5 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 40253a7c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 40253a8c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): memory near ip:
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 00003fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 00003ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 00004000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 00004010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 00004020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): memory near sp:
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a8298 00000000 4021ec89 00000001 7e7a82bc  ......!@......z~
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82a8 00000002 00000002 df0027ad 00000000  .........'......
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82b8 75ff7ec2 fffffbdf 4023dbfc 00000002  .~.u......#@....
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82c8 00000002 4021e1f5 40247718 75ff7ec2  ......!@.w$@.~.u
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 7e7a82d8 4023dbfc 40210c08 7e7a82e0 402220e3  ..#@..!@..z~. "@
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): code around pc:
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021b308 e000b164 6823461c d1fb2b00 68e3e026  d....F#h.+..&..h
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021b318 4a17b123 447a2401 47986014 20274911  #..J.$zD.`.G.I'
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021b328 70082400 eb9cf7f4 f7f52106 a902ecdc  .$.p.....!......
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021b338 f04f2006 460a5380 94029304 f7f59403  . O..S.F........
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021b348 4629e8ba 20024622 e8c2f7f5 eb88f7f4  ..)F"F. ........
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): code around lr:
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021ec68 41f0e92d 4c0b2600 447c4680 68a56824  -..A.&.L.F|D$h.h
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021ec78 e0076867 300cf9b5 dd022b00 47c04628  gh.....0.+..(F.G
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021ec88 35544306 d5f53f01 2c006824 4630d1ef  .CT5.?..$h.,..0F
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021ec98 81f0e8bd 0002888e 43f0e92d fb01461f  ........-..C.F..
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): 4021eca8 f8dff602 b0878058 44f8460c 8000f8d8  ....X....F.D....
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): memory map around fault addr deadbaad:
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): be8ef000-be910000 [stack]
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): (no map for address)
12-11 00:10:38.146: INFO/DEBUG(166): ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
12-11 00:10:38.536: INFO/BootReceiver
```

Comment: It looks like you are accessing memory that's not accessible. Check `Java_name_antonsmirnov_clang_clang_1wrapper_getDiagnostics` line 72 and the pointer you are passing to `clang::cxdiag::lazyCreateDiags`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was concurrency issue. Clang methods/structures seem to be not thread-safe so one have to synchronize access. One more suggestion: do not share the same `JNIEnv*` between threads! use `vm>GetEnv()` from within a thread to get JNIEnv pointer.